# Is there any significance to uniform color on Stargate Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In *Stargate Atlantis*, the team going to Atlantis wears uniforms not seen before in *Stargate: SG-1*. They consist of a shirt & trousers covered with a jacket (very similar to later *Star Trek: The Next Generation* uniforms, actually).

Some are dark grey with maroon highlights, and some are tan with blue highlights. The color doesn't seem to indicate rank or science vs. military - characters are seen wearing both colors at different points during the show.

[image: Woman in red uniform, next to man in a blue uniform]

**Is there any significance to the different colored uniforms on *Stargate Atlantis*, or is it just whichever color you choose to wear that day?**

Comment: "Teyla Emmagan" was a Athosian Tribal "Primary" (Matriarch/Queen) of the Todd's Alliance, representing the people of Athos in the Pegasus Galaxy. Whether that required any Military Training is unclear, so if you had to "Pin" a color to her. It would probably be RED...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the [*Stargate Atlantis* Wiki](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Atlantis_expedition)

> *In addition to this, each member has a flag patch that contains the flag of the member's home country. Though the most common uniforms are almost all charcoal black, some members have been seen with all-khaki uniforms. They are also color coded. **The colors indicate what specialty the members are part of:***
>
> ***Red** (command/civilian)
>
> **Blue** (scientist)
>
> **Yellow** (medical)
>
> **Black** (military)
>
> **Green** (technician)*

There's also an additional colour seen in *SGA* 2x05 which appears to be a grey-panelled suit corresponding to Special Ops(?).

Please note that these colours are not always portrayed consistently, other than for the main cast. Various extras have been seen wearing red and blue despite not being Command or Science. Teyla also [wears red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMBgH.jpg) for no discernible reason.

---

**Command**
[image: Woman from command, in a red uniform]

**Science**
[image: scientist in a blue uniform]

**Medical**
[image: Medic (yellow uniform)]

**Military**
[image: Military officer (black uniform)]

**Technical**
[image: Techincal guy (green uniform)]

**Special Operations/Military?**
[image: Black/grey uniform]

Comment: Teyla's outfit doesn't have any color over the chest area of her shirt and instead has color on her shoulders. I don't think it's intended to be like any of the other expedition uniforms. I suspect the conversation went something like: "Alright, she didn't bring any spare clothes with her when fleeing her planet, and we can't order any from Earth, so let's just make due with changing one of our uniforms. Was anybody chosen for this expedition based on their sewing skills?"

Comment: @Thunderforge - Presumably they just grabbed something that fits her. It's not like she's not instantly recognisable, nor is anyone likely to mistake her for a full command officer. Possibly it's in respect of her being an 'ambassador' to the locals, but that wasn't established until later in the show

Comment: @Thunderforge - And without seeming crass, her uniform needs to have a custom-cut in order to accentuate her *general chestal area* since that was clearly one of the main considerations when casting the role.

Comment: I see what you mean about the color-coding now. I think it was mostly the gray vs. khaki that was throwing me off. Also, I'm pretty sure Beckett wore both blue and yellow at various times, but maybe the yellow came in a later season?

Comment: Several episodes later, I realize part of my confusion. The shirts worn under the jacket are all the bluish-gray color, which on my screen looks pretty close to the Sciences blue on the jacket. Except for Weir, who almost always wears a red shirt. And after season 3, seems like half the cast changed to a different, more military-looking uniform (like dark gray fatigues) while others still wore the older uniforms. Wild.

Comment: As for the red uniforms, somewhere on the Internet I read an assumption that red is for diplomatic oriented staff, so that may be reason why Teyla got red uniform as well.